# Rear motorized hatch in 2005 Nissan Armada will not open

Tags: electrical, nissan, door

My 2005 Nissan Armada rear hatch has opened unexpectedly (while parked) several times in the past few weeks. Now the rear hatch will not open with either the key fob or via the interior hatch button. Also the exterior handle will not allow it to open either manually or set off the auto open. What could cause this problem?

Comment: Were you ever able to get that hatch repaired and do you recall what the issue was?

Answer (score -1):

The simple fact is that the rear hatch is either physically damaged or there is a problem with the electrical system. If you're not already familiar with how to repair it, you just need to take it to the dealership.